# Mysql, Where to add quotes

Tags: mysql

```
insert into mmm (EDATE, IDNO, TUITION, MISC, TERM, SYFROM, SYTO)    
 values ('2005-12-23',94587896,12000,1215,"3rd".2006,2007);
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into mmm (EDATE, IDNO, TUITION, MISC, TERM, SYFROM, SYTO)
> values ('2005-1' at line 2

Comment: When your data type is other than number related data type but you can use quotes on numbers data type as well

Comment: The error indicates that there is something right at the beginning of your query. Do you try to execute 2 queries at once and this is the second?

Comment: ENO INT not null auto_increment,
    -> EDATE DATE,
    -> IDNO INT not null,
    -> TUITION INT,
    -> MISC INT,
    -> TERM CHAR(3),
    -> SYFROM INT(4),
    -> SYTO INT(4),
    -> PRIMARY KEY (ENO));

Comment: As mentioned, the error relates to whatever happens immediately before this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem that I can see is the dot(.) instead of comma(,) between "3rd" and 2006 in your code. Try this and see if your problem gets fixed.

```
insert into mmm (EDATE, IDNO, TUITION, MISC, TERM, SYFROM, SYTO)
values('2005-12-23', 94587896, 12000, 1215, '3rd', 2006, 2007);
```

Comment: It says: ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1